# How can I redirect to a particular page in an angular hybrid application? (Android)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Let me explain the problem here.
I'm using Cordova to wrap my web application and run it on Android.
For login in I'm using an external page that takes a URL to which it should redirect in my app. What I want to achieve is to reload my index.html and go to the passed url or path, for example: /settings/bookies

I know how to do this in a hosted website (the web app) but on my cordova application paths seems to be different and I don't know how to redirect.
In my web app I would redirect to 'http://www.mywebsite.com/settings/bookies?loginToken=token' but for the cordova app I've tried redirecting to 'file:///settings/bookies' but it says:
“Not allowed to load local resource: file:///settings/bookies”

Any ideas of what should I do in this case?
thanks for your help in advance and I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Why did you try the `file` protocol? You may need to look into AngularJS routing.

Comment: Hey! I'm using Angular routing. I've checked with `$location` service and the absolute path I get when in Cordova is `file///settings/bookies`
That's why I tried using that for redirecting but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

before taking using user to your domain read the current url using `window.location.href`

this returns protocol,hostname,port,path,search,hash

say if you know that you are at file://assets/index.html .. then remove index.html from it  "file://assets/" is now your base path. Then add your relative path to it  and pass this redirect path to your remote page.

in your case it would become "file://assets/settings/bookies"

it will vary for android and iOS

Comment: thanks so much for your answer! I'll give it a shot and will let you know if it works.

Comment: When using `window.location.href` I get:
`file:///settings/bookies `